# What exactly do these arguments mean in linux?

Tags: c, linux, parameter-passing

I have a program written in C and the command I am supposed to run it with on linux looks like this:

```
./program --something X Y
```

What exactly does that mean? I think X Y will be the arguments so `argc[2]` will be `X` and `argc[3]` will be `Y`?

But what about `--something`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why would it be any different? it will be passed through `argv` as well. (and **not** through `argc`, that's just the length of the `argv` array.)

Comment: `argv[1]` would seem logical. No? This is something you can learn from any beginners C book or tutorial and suggest you go through something like that to learn the basics in a systematic way.

Comment: You mention `argv[2]` and `argv[3]`. What would go in `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`?

Comment: yes, it's just text. Starting with "-" or "--" or anything else is just program's convention.

Comment: You should look into `getopt`.

Comment: I was just confused about the -- in front of the word so I thought it might be something special.

Comment: Also I wonder, why is everyone giving my question a thumbs down? Was it really that stupid? I did try to research that but could not find anything and was confused by the first argument and needed a quick answer. So sorry if it came across as not useful, unclear or not showing any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C runtime does not discriminate any arguments, whether they start with `--` or not. So you have,

```
argv[0] = "./program"
argv[1] = "--something"
argv[2] = "X"
argv[3] = "Y"
argv[4] = NULL
```

It is your program that assigns meaning to those values.

Answer (score 0):

Anything following the command itself will get to `argv`:

`argv[1]` is `--something`, `argv[2]` is `X` and `argv[3]` is `Y`. Following the *unix conventions, this would mean your program has a parameter called "something" with a value of "X", and "Y" is the argument the program should be applied on - but that's completely up to your implementation of the program.

Comment: It's also possible (and even common) that `--something` takes no parameter.

Answer (score 0):

These arguments are no different from others as far as `argc` and `argv` are concerned.

What makes them different is that many Linux tools (but not only) use [`getopt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) to make it easier to make sense of those options. This is particularly useful when you need more than a couple of possible options (or can't remember what they're for).

You can generally have long and short options, with and without arguments.

The convention is also to have `--help` print out a summary of all the available options.

For example, with the help for `man`:

```
$ man --help
Usage: man [OPTION...] [SECTION] PAGE...

  -C, --config-file=FILE     use this user configuration file
  -d, --debug                emit debugging messages
  -D, --default              reset all options to their default values
      --warnings[=WARNINGS]  enable warnings from groff
```

In this particular example, you can use either `-d` or `--debug` to turn on debugging. `getopt` (or similar) is used to parse `-d` or `--debug` into something meaningful. `-C` or `--config-file` would also be equivalent, but expect an argument.

There are similar equivalents in other languages (for example [Python's argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html), or Apache Commons CLI in Java).

Comment: Thanks a lot as well! : )